# node https module send file to php server

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, http, https

How to send HTTP post request that include a jpg file to php server with node https module?
I tried using request module but its unreliable (timed out most of the time) and its already deprecated.

This is my node upload function

```js
function uploadScreen() {
var data = querystring.stringify({file: fs.createReadStream( path.join( os.tmpdir() , 'screen.jpg' ) )});
var header = {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg','Content-Length': data.length, 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 ' + os.type() + ' Client','X-Requested-With': global.id};
var server = {hostname: 'server.net', port: 443, path: '/upload.php', method: 'POST', headers:header};
var req = https.request(server, (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);
    res.on('data', (d) => {process.stdout.write(d);});
});
req.on('error', (e) => {console.error(e);});
req.write(data);
req.end();
}
```

I receive it with my php server like this

```php
<?php
$target_dir = "../";
$obj=(object)$_FILES['file'];
$userid = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'];
$name=date("Ymd")."-".$userid."-".date("His").".jpg";
$tmp=$obj->tmp_name;


move_uploaded_file($tmp, $target_dir.$name);
?>
```

My php server return HTTP 200 to my node client but with no files uploaded. All the header were sent correctly but the body doesn't. According to my access.log the server only receive 5 bytes of data.
The weird thing is, this is working with the old deprecated request module although unreliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `axios` HTTP client.

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios
```

You can modify your code like this:

```
const axios = require('axios');

...

async function uploadScreen() {
  try {
    let image = fs.readFileSync(path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'screen.jpg'));
    let sending_image_result = await axios({
       method: 'post',
       url: 'https://server.net:443/upload.php',
       data: {
         file: image 
       },
       headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'image/jpg',
       },
    });
    //Image is send
    console.log('Result: ', sending_image_result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error: ', error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your help, but i still cannot save it. PHP message: PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "file"

Comment: Can you console the incoming request body in the PHP, to check how the data comes to the server. The data should be in the request.body 'file' property. And also try `console.log('Image: ', image)` in NodeJS to check if the data is being send properly.

Comment: Nevermind, i fixed my php code. The client send it as binary blob instead of form data. So i modify my server just to dump the http body. Thanks for all your help

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. Consider to approve and upvote my answer if it helped you.